# Updating Images in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php

I am on my way to create the feature for users to upload their profile photo to the database. I manage to upload my photo to database in binary form (BLOB) but I am having problem while trying to display it.

upload form code:

```
<?php //get the posted image when the submit button is clicked 
$username = "MentorMenteeData"; 
$password = "mentormenteedata"; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$database = "mentormenteesystem"; 

// Make the connect to MySQL or die 
// and display an error. 
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

// Select your database 
mysql_select_db ($database);         

   if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

      // Temporary file name stored on the server 
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];   

      // Read the file 
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); 
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName)); 
      $data = addslashes($data); 
      fclose($fp); 

      $student_id=$row_student['student_id']; 

      // Create the query and insert 
      // into our database. 
      $query = "UPDATE student SET student_img='$data' WHERE student_id ='$student_id'"; 
      $query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')"; 
      $results = mysql_query($query, $link); 

      // Print results 
      print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded."; 

} 
else { 
   print "No image selected/uploaded"; 
} 

// Close our MySQL Link 
mysql_close($link); 
?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="changer"> 

<strong style="color: #FFD700;">Upload your image:</strong><br /> 
<input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="102400" type="hidden"><br /><br /> 
<input namge="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Code to display image:

```
<?php 

$username = "MentorMenteeData"; 
$password = "mentormenteedata"; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$database = "mentormenteesystem"; 

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error()); 

$id = $_REQUEST['student_id']; 

if(!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)){ 
     die("Please select your image!"); 
}else{ 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id='".$id."'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
$content = $row['image']; 
} 

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
     echo $content; 
?>
```

I could see my database table for the image column containing some bits but I just cant seems to display it. Please advise.

Comment: Don't store the actual image in the database... store it in the filesystem, and just hold the path to that file in the database

Answer (score 2):

Your code to retrieve and display the image looks like it is correct, however I'm guessing you are never getting to the query due to this filtering line:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['student_id']; 

if(!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)){ 
     die("Please select your image!"); 
}
```

[`is_int()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.is-int.php) tests if the type of a value is an integer, and values coming from `$_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST` are always strings. , so your condition is *always false*. You can test it instead with [`ctype_digit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.ctype-digit.php) or [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.is-numeric.php), or `intval($id) == $id`. Also, `empty()` calls `isset()` implicitly, so `isset()` isn't needed.

```
// ctype_digit() method...
if (empty($id) || !ctype_digit($id)) { 
     die("Please select your image!");
}

// intval() method...
if (empty($id) || (intva($id) != $id)) { 
  die("Please select your image!"); 
}
```

Comment: So, how could I get the image to be visible? what happen if I delete this line "if(!isset($id) || empty($id) || !is_int($id)){ 
     die("Please select your image!"); 
}" ? Will this help?

Comment: @Steve87 Just replace that line with either one of my two suggestions. Don't delete it, as you need it to properly validate your `$id` against SQL injection. Leave the `else {}` that follows it intact.

Answer (score 1):

Without any errors, it's hard to say, but if it's not the ID problem as suggested by Michael, it might [also] be corruption of your image data on upload. Have you tried downloading the directly (eg `wget` that URL) and opening it locally? Is the JPEG header there?

Some general comments:

1. Are you sure you want to store images in the database? It's
   generally preferred to store filename / URL fragments, and leave the
   binary data on disk, especially if they're larger images. See
   [php:Store image into Mysql blob, Good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313969/phpstore-image-into-mysql-blob-good-or-bad)
   for a discussion.
2. Either way that upload code is asking for trouble. `addslashes()` is
   not sufficient to fix the escaping problem, use a specific one like
   [mysqli::real escape-string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
   to safeguard against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
   attacks - [this post](http://cognifty.com/blog.entry?id=6/addslashes_dont_call_it_a_comeback.html) explores some differences.
3. If your MySQL DB is hosted on the same box as your webserver, you
   could even save effort (and increase speed) by using the [MySQL LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function, but this isn't very scalable in the long term.
4. Consider moving all your login details to a separate file, out of the webroot for security.