# Inserting Binary into MySQL BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, blob

```
$serv = "xxx";
$user = "xxx"; 
$pass = "xxx"; 
$db = "xxx"; 

$imgloc = "../images/bg.jpg"; 
$image = fopen($imgloc, 'rb'); 
$imageContent = fread($image, filesize($imgloc)); 

$conn = new mysqli($serv, $user, $pass, $db); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `image`(`advert_id`,`img`) VALUES('1','" . $imageContent . "');"; 
$conn->query($sql);
```

I'm using the above code to try to insert binary into my MySQL database but nothing is being sent to the database. The $imageContent just appears in the database as null but if I echo $imageContent it seems to show binary data.

advert_id is just a int field and img is a BLOB

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). you can't just stuff random binary garbage into a query string and expect things to work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: What functions should I use to clean it?

Comment: As a tangential comment, I would recommend making sure that you REALLY have a good use case for storing images blobs in MySQL.   In a lot of cases, this might not be a good idea when compared to simply storing file references in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is because you need to escape your data.

```
$imageContent = fread($image, filesize($imgloc)); 
$imageContent = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $imageContent);
```

You are not seeing the syntax error, similar to:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8   16@#54' at line 1...

- Because you are not checking for errors.

Visit http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php, then use the following at the top of your file:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// rest of your code
```

This will signal syntax errors.

---

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

---

Plus, as Mike Brant said in comments, and I quote:

*"As a tangential comment, I would recommend making sure that you REALLY have a good use case for storing images blobs in MySQL. In a lot of cases, this might not be a good idea when compared to simply storing file references in the database."*

- Mike speaks the truth. Your database will increase dramatically over time, therefore storing a copy of your files in a folder then making a reference to it, is usually a better idea, but that is entirely up to you.

Read the following Q&A's on Stack:

- [php:Store image into Mysql blob, Good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6313969/)
- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/)