# PHP - file not uploaded into the database using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, mysqli

I made an upload file code without prepared statements. The file is successfully uploaded. But when I add prepared statements to the code, the contents of the file is not uploaded. Only the file name, size and type and uploaded in the database.

This is the code:

PHP:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  ){

//user has the option whether to upload the file or not
if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$allowed =  array('zip','rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(in_array($ext, $allowed)){           

        if($filesize < 2000000) {

            //$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filedata`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filedata','$filetype','$filesize')"; <- old code line

            $query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filedata`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("sbsi", $filename, $filedata, $filetype,$filesize);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->errno){
            echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
            } else {
            echo "<br>Inserted";
            }
            $stmt->close(); 

            /* if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) <- old code line
            {
            echo "Uploaded<br>";

            } else {
            echo "Error! <br>" . $con->error;
            }   */

        } else {

        $errorMsg = "Sorry, your file is too large. Only 2MB is allowed";
        }

    }else{
        $errorMsg = "Sorry, only zip, rar, pdf, doc & docx are allowed.";        
    }

//if user has no file to upload then proceed to this else statement
} else {

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

//$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filedata`, `filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES ('$filename','$filetype','$filesize')"; <- old code line

$query = "INSERT INTO contracts(`filename`,`filetype`,`filesize`) VALUES (?,?,?)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $filename, $filetype,$filesize);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->errno){
            echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
            } else {
            echo "<br>Inserted";
            }
            $stmt->close(); 

        /*  if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) <- old code line
            {
            echo "Uploaded<br>";

            } else {
            echo "Error! <br>" . $con->error;
            }   */

}

$con->close(); 
}   

?>
```

HTML:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php echo $errorMsg; ?>
Upload File:
<input type="file" name="upload" /><br> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the contents of the file is not uploaded and missing in the database with prepared statements? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: in your query you simply insert  `filename`,`filetype`,`filesize`  .. and not the file itself ..

Comment: prepared statement means not to use `real_escape_string`

Comment: @Deadooshka so I don't have to use prepared statements to prevent sql injection for uploading file?

Comment: you have to read the file content using file_get_content and set to a field

Comment: @Ima can you show me an example dear sir?

Comment: @ima Op is reading the file into `$filedata`

Comment: How is the `filedata` column defined in your schema

Comment: Why do you want to store file content into database? My suggestion is store file path in database & save the file itself in disk.

Comment: this is purely a choice OP have to make depending on his needs. It's not because evryone has a car than you don't need a truck. This said, i would suggest the same as you did.

Comment: Show us the database structure also. And  print the  `$filedata` to know the exact content of the variable.

Comment: Not related, but you should not escape your data when you use a prepared statement.

Comment: And why are you trying to store information in the database when the file-size is 0 (the `else` section)?

Comment: Are you trying to store the SAME FILE while testing this script as you did when successfully testing the other script???

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES['upload']['error']` to see if an error code exists and then check what that code means?

Comment: If you escape the contents of the file, you risk changing the bytes in the file. Possibly the escaping is causing byte 0 to become a zero and hense everything thinks the file has no content other than an end of file

Comment: If you want to store a file into the database it is nornal to convert the bytes in the file into a base64encoded string before attempting to store the file into the table and then convert it back when you want to see it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php ((PHP 5, PHP 7) (Assuming your $conn object is good and working).

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("sbsi", $filename, $filedata, $filetype,$filesize);
$stmt->send_long_data(1, file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])); 
$stmt->execute();
```

PS : 1 represent the bind argument associated staring from 0, in your case the blob (b) is 2nd, so 1 on a 0 count.

THis is untested and i never used it, i just knew i could be done. Hopefully it will help.

More on the oracle blog : https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing

You might want to escape your binary, see [Inserting Binary into MySQL BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174824/inserting-binary-into-mysql-blob)

Another version from php.net :

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("sbsi", $filename, $filedata, $filetype,$filesize);
$fp = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(1, fread($fp,$filesize));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You could also consider storing only he filepath in your DB and store the file as a file, but this is purely a choice you have to mkae on you needs.

Comment: It displayed `Warning: : failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\contractdb\filetest.php on line 28`

Comment: change $filedata to your file path $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], will edit answer

Comment: Good to know, never used it. The only time i stored images in a db was somewhat sensitive data and was years ago. Sorry for making you my tester :)

Comment: Also, as mentioned, you might want to escape your data;

Answer (score -1):

If your database column type of `filedata` is long enough to accept file content, you can do this.

1. Check the field type of `filedata`. 
   Suggestion:make type of column `filedata` a text or blob
2. Now check if you file is actually uploaded to server. You can do this by printing the file content

Use following code to check if file is actually uploaded

```
if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] != 0 ){

$filename = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$filedata= $con->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']));
$filetype = $con->real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['type']);
$filesize = intval($_FILES['upload']['size']);

$allowed =  array('zip','rar', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx');
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Print the details to check if file is actually uploaded. 
//Note: Remove this line after debugging
print_r([$filename, $filedata, $filetype, $filesize, $ext]); exit;
```

Comment: It prints `Array ( [0] => Document 1.docx [1] => a long line of gibberish unicode [2] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document [3] => 10964 [4] => docx)

Comment: This means the file is being uploaded successfully. Now check your db structure to find if the long string fit in the column `filedata`. I hope you already fixed this.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote here.
This is not a full solution to the problem, the original author used my suggestion to troubleshoot their problem and verified the first part of the problem is not there and  I think they went forward with next part of the problem